How to call an async function from a child thread using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe() and the main thread's loop?
I have an application that runs using async/await everywhere. Often, it calls out to functions that are synchronous. Those functions sometimes have to call asynchronous functions again. I am trying to make this work by using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe() from a thread, using the main thread's loop, but waiting for run_coroutine_threadsafe()'s Future to complete by calling .result() is what appears to hang.
The following is my sample code that reproduces the problem on Python 3.12 and 3.13:
from asyncio import run_coroutine_threadsafe, get_running_loop, run, AbstractEventLoop
from collections.abc import Callable, Awaitable
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")


def _await_in_thread(loop: AbstractEventLoop, f: Callable[[], Awaitable[_T]]) -> _T:
    """
    Await something inside a thread, using the main thread's loop.
    """

    print("THIS IS PRINTED")
    return run_coroutine_threadsafe(f(), loop).result()


def _await_to_thread(pool: ThreadPoolExecutor, f: Callable[[], Awaitable[_T]]) -> _T:
    """
    Await something by moving it to a thread.
    """
    return pool.submit(_await_in_thread, get_running_loop(), f).result()


async def _async_main(pool: ThreadPoolExecutor) -> None:
    """
    Run the main application, which is asynchronous.
    """

    # Eventually, the application calls a function that due to its nature (maybe a third-party API) is synchronous.
    _some_sync_function(pool)


def _sync_main() -> None:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        run(_async_main(pool))


def _some_sync_function(pool: ThreadPoolExecutor) -> None:
    # This synchronous function then has to call a function that is asynchronous.
    result = _await_to_thread(pool, _some_async_function)
    assert result == 123


async def _some_async_function() -> int:
    print("BUT THIS IS NOT PRINTED")
    return 123


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _sync_main()


While the sample could have been slightly simpler, I wanted to include usage of the ThreadPoolExecutor, as well as propagation of the return value, as those are two requirements of the final product (as well as using the same loop across the multiple threads).
Additionally, Python compatibility is 3.11+, but I may be convinced to make that 3.12+ if there is no other solution.
This is the result of a single answer on IRC and the very succinct examples of run_coroutine_threadsafe() I found in the Python documentation as well as on various Q&A sites and blogs. It does not appear to be a feature that is commonly known or used by folks.
My question is: what did I misunderstand, and how should this work?

You are experiencing a deadlock.
From asyncio's event loop you are sumbitting a function to the pool, but also awaiting the result. During that waiting time the event loop is blocked (this should not happen in asyncio!). It happens here:
return pool.submit(_await_in_thread, get_running_loop(), f).result()

which is equivalent to:
future = pool.sumbit(...)
return future.result()  # wait for the result synchronously!

This sumbitted function sumbits another function, this time to asyncio and it again waits for the result. Same pattern as above, the actual code:
return run_coroutine_threadsafe(f(), loop).result()

But asyncio cannot do any work, because it is blocked as stated above.
To correct the problem, the program logic must be revisited.

Thank you. This is what I theorized on IRC when a user there confirmed this was the solution to my problem. However, they, as well as the documentation and numerous blog posts say that this is the way to run an async function from a sync function while an event loop is running already. It's not ideal, but such are the constraints of complex application environments.

Yes, it's little bit complex, but manageable. For example if you need to call from asyncio a sync function SF and from within that SF an async function AF, you could declare the SF with async def and await it. From within the noe async SF await directly the AF. Thus you'll get a continuous "pipe" of awaits from the main asyncio function through the SF up to the AF - that's how asyncio scheduling works.

Can you explain what you mean with "you could declare the SF with async def"? Do you mean making the synchronous function asynchronous?

The correct word I should have used in my comment is "pipeline", not pipe.

@Xano, Yes, I mean that. You can convert your regular function to a coroutine function (i.e. async function). def f(): becomes async def f():. Invoking it becomes retval = await f() instead of retval = f(). Then you can invoke (i.e. await) any other async function from it. Of course, you can do it with your own code only, not with some given API.

Making existing functions asynchronous is unfortunately exactly what is not possible (because it's not my code). If it had been, the entire premise of this question would be irrelevant.

You say, "I have an application that runs using async/await everywhere. Often, it calls out to functions that are synchronous. Those functions sometimes have to call asynchronous functions again. I am trying to make this work by using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe() ...".
I think there is a simpler way than using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe() as follows. Have your async function invoke a non-async function by using run_in_executor and await its completion and get its return value if you need it. Since the non-async function is running in another thread, it can invoke an async function directly using asyncio.run. Here is a demo:
Note
You have a thread running an event loop and currently executing an asyncio function. You need that async function to somehow invoke a  synchronous function and for that synchronous function to then somehow invoke an asynchronous function:
async_funtion_1 -> sync_function -> async_function_2

You want the async_function_2 to return a value back to sync_function.
You do not want to create a second event loop.
You do not want to block the main event loop that async_function_1 is running in since there could be other tasks running in that event loop.

Once you call a synchronous function directly from an asynchronous function (e.g. with sync_funtion_1()) the current thread's event loop will be blocked because there is no way for sync_function_1 to await anything and there is no magic you can perform by creating another thread and attempting for that thread to invoke an asynchronous function in the blocked main thread's event loop.
The only way to have sync_function invoke async_function_2 is by running async_function_2 in another running event loop executing in another thread. And if you want to ensure that the main thread's event loop is not blocked (the third requirement above), then you do not directly call sync_function() from async_function_1 but rather execute it in a thread pool with loop.run_in_executor and then have sync_function invoke async_function_2 using asyncio.run(), as I have done.
Perhaps it would have been better if you had mentioned that you are constrained with having only one event loop ever executing. You would have been told this is impossible without a re-architecture.
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

POOL_SIZE = 1  # For demo purposes

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(POOL_SIZE)

async def async_function():
    print("I am async")
    return 1

def non_async_function():
    return asyncio.run(async_function())

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    print(await loop.run_in_executor(executor, non_async_function))

asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
I am async
1


Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the solution you suggest creates multiple event loops, which is something I need to avoid due to third-party libraries binding themselves to a specific running loop.

See the note I have added to the answer. Perhaps you should post a new question with all the requirements and describe more fully how your code interacts with the third-party libraries. Then you might get a suggestion on what you need to change in your code. But clearly a re-architecture is required.

The original question already included the bit about reusing the main thread's event loop. I did update the post earlier today to clarify it's a hard requirement.

I could see you were reusing the main thread's event loop, which was doomed to failure, but I did not have a full appreciation of why that was your approach.

Fair enough. Practically speaking I believe it's mostly been aiohttp's ClientSession that's given me headaches here.
In the meantime I did rearchitect 98% of use cases of my await-something-in-a-thread workaround that caused the problems with shared loops and what not (with the final usage scheduled for removal soon). While practically, I am about to no longer have this problem, I'm still interested in the answer to my original question (the theory behind how Python does this things (or not, and understanding the reasoning behind such a limitation)).

Maybe you should post a more complete description of your situation, preferably in a new question since this one was closed since there seemed to already be an answer based on limited knowledge of what your constraints were.
